# data of current month from date column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I m trying to retrieve data of current month from mysql table with a date data type column. **here is my query which return nothing**

```
SELECT *
  FROM `overview` AS s1 INNER JOIN
       `payments` AS s2 ON s1.Booking_id = s2.Booking_id
 WHERE YEAR(s1.Booking_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
   AND MONTH(s1.Booking_date) = MONTH(CURDATE());
```

```
First table :**overview**
S_no          Int (auto increment) Primary Key
Booking_id    varchar
Booking_Date  Date(YYYY-mm-dd)
```

```
**Second table**
Booking_id  Primary Key
price       int
```

I will really appreciate if anyone can provide a stored procedure for the above code.

Comment: What's a stored procedure got to do with the price of fish?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Check your JOIN. Make sure you're using the correct columns. Also, calling YEAR() and MONTH() on king_date will keep any index from working, so this will be slowing down the SELECT tremendously. I'd recommend going back to my favorite and create a Date Dimension table, then INNER JOINing to that.

Answer (score 0):

Does just this query return anything for you?

```
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      `overview` AS s1
    INNER JOIN
      `payments` AS s2
    ON
      s1.id = s2.id
```

It's unusual that two separate tables would have the same primary key. Usually you use a foreign key when doing table joins. Is it possible that your date logic is correct but the main part of your query is wrong? I'm just guessing because I don't know your database schema.

Comment: the query i mentioned returns nothing but an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Your join with `payments` table is wrong. Correct query is as under. You need to replace `s2.overview_id` with your correct column name.

```
SELECT *
  FROM `overview` AS s1 INNER JOIN
       `payments` AS s2 ON s1.id = s2.overview_id
 WHERE YEAR(s1.king_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
   AND MONTH(s1.king_date) = MONTH(CURDATE());
```

Using this you can create a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `spName`()
    BEGIN
    SELECT *
  FROM `overview` AS s1 INNER JOIN
       `payments` AS s2 ON s1.id = s2.overview_id
 WHERE YEAR(s1.king_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
   AND MONTH(s1.king_date) = MONTH(CURDATE());
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

For create stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GetPaymentsofCurrentMonth()
   BEGIN
     SELECT *
     FROM `overview` AS s1 INNER JOIN
       `payments` AS s2 ON s1.id = s2.id
     WHERE YEAR(s1.king_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
     AND MONTH(s1.king_date) = MONTH(CURDATE());
   END
```

Call your stored procedure:

```
CALL GetPaymentsofCurrentMonth();
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem. My query was correct the problem was the data column which was holding random due to excel data import. which i corrected. Now Its working fine. By converting custom cell property to text in excel file.